# How much floor space does a basic multigym need?

Tags: exercise-equipment, home-exercise

I'm setting up a dedicated home gym in a room about 4x3.5m (13x12' approx) with a high ceiling.
I'm interested in a multigym and two cardio machines (bike+x-trainer) but how much space does a multigym need... Not for itself but to enable it to be used? How much 'envelope' around it should be planned?

Comment: That would depend entirely on the individual brand/piece of equipment.

Comment: Anywhere from 50 - 200 square feet in general, depending on the footprint. You also need to factor in the space to move around it comfortably. Typical treadmill will need 25-30 square feet, about the same depending on the cross trainer you are considering.